# How to click on text in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, firefox, testing, automated-tests, selenium-ide

There is an extension for Firefox called Selenium IDE. How do I click just on an element containing text in Selenium IDE? As an example, let's imagine I want to post an ad on Gumtree (in reality I don't, it's just the simplest publicly visible example I can think of).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://www.gumtree.com/" />
<title>gumtree</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">gumtree</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>https://my.gumtree.com/postad</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td> *** what do I put in here to choose "For Sale"? *** </td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td> *** what do I put in here to choose "House Clearance"? *** </td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>id=continueButton</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to find element locators for these elements. Good thing is that Selenium IDE can you do it for you (in recording mode).

Try following locators..

```
For sale 
//form[@id='frmSyi']/div/div/div/div/nav/ul/li[2]/div/span
or
//li[2]/div/span[2]
```

===========

```
House Clearance
//form[@id='frmSyi']/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[11]
or
//li[11]
```

NOTE: Use **ClickAt** command instead of Click for clicking on House Clearance.

Comment: This does not seem to work as it keeps changing on the project I have (not gumtree). Why is it not possible through text? What could be easier?

Comment: Also the changes you suggested do not seem to work, Selenium does not see where to click and stops. Did you try them on your end? Can you provide a full xml then?

Comment: This was just to give you an idea. Of course you will need to find element locators in case of your application. Most of the time Selenium IDE finds them automatically. Otherwise you need to use dev tools like firegbug etc. I can help you further only if you share HTML of your application.

Comment: and yes it worked for me. I have tried it in my selenium IDE for Gumtree.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for element by text usually is a bad idea because such test will not be suitable for every localisation and will be pretty fragile in case of any text changes. That's why Selenium IDE doesn't do it out-of-the-box. So you should do it using xpath anyway. But you can use your text in your xpath:

```
click | //*[contains(text(),'For Sale')]
click | //*[text()='House Clearance']
```

**The first command** will click the first element that contains 'For Sale' text.

**The second command** will click the first element with text exactly equal 'House Clearance'

**Be careful** - It is highly possible that there is more than one element with such text on the page (that's another reason why it's not good to use text). In that case your xpath should be more detailed. For example if your element is a span like:

```
<span>For Sale</span>
```

You can use xpath=//span[text()='For Sale']

You can read more about xpath [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are determinant, you can try:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("ElementText")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("ElementText")).click();
```